# Como atualizar o SDK Tools?

Tags: android-studio

baixei a biblioteca Glide com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0 que da esse erro do gradle: Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1

Ja procurei a sdk tools 25.3.1 no sdk manager, mas não existe, vai até 25.0 depois pula pra 26.0. Baixei a 26 mas o erro continua